# Google Drive API: no way to list entries under 'Computers'

Tags: google-drive-api

When using 'Files: list' API (1) there is no way to list only the entries which in Google Drive's web interface are listed under 'Computers' folder.
In the API response those entries are returned as orphaned, that is, they don't have the 'parents' sub-object.
However there is no query ('q' parameter) that could be used to list only those entries.

Below an excerpt of 'Files: list' API JSON result showing one of 'Computers' entries (sensitive data removed):

```json
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "<id>",
   "name": "My laptop",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
   "starred": false,
   "trashed": false,
   "explicitlyTrashed": false,
   "spaces": [
    "drive"
   ],
   "version": "739",
   "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/<id>",
   "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
   "hasThumbnail": false,
   "thumbnailVersion": "0",
   "viewedByMe": true,
   "viewedByMeTime": "2020-07-05T20:51:53.319Z",
   "createdTime": "2019-07-26T10:31:14.366Z",
   "modifiedTime": "2019-07-26T10:31:14.366Z",
   "modifiedByMeTime": "2019-07-26T10:31:14.366Z",
   "modifiedByMe": true,
   "owners": [
    {
     "kind": "drive#user",
     "displayName": "<name>",
     "photoLink": "<url>",
     "me": true,
     "permissionId": "<permid>",
     "emailAddress": "<email>"
    }
   ],
   "lastModifyingUser": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "<name>",
    "photoLink": "<url>",
    "me": true,
    "permissionId": "<permid>",
    "emailAddress": "<email>"
   },
   "shared": false,
   "ownedByMe": true,
   "capabilities": {
    "canAddChildren": true,
    "canAddMyDriveParent": false,
    "canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
    "canChangeViewersCanCopyContent": false,
    "canComment": true,
    "canCopy": false,
    "canDelete": true,
    "canDownload": true,
    "canEdit": true,
    "canListChildren": true,
    "canModifyContent": true,
    "canMoveChildrenWithinDrive": true,
    "canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive": true,
    "canMoveItemOutOfDrive": true,
    "canMoveItemWithinDrive": true,
    "canReadRevisions": false,
    "canRemoveChildren": true,
    "canRemoveMyDriveParent": true,
    "canRename": true,
    "canShare": false,
    "canTrash": true,
    "canUntrash": true
   },
   "viewersCanCopyContent": true,
   "copyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
   "writersCanShare": true,
   "folderColorRgb": "#8f8f8f",
   "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
   "isAppAuthorized": false
  },
```

Any idea?

EDIT: screenshots as requested

How to configure PC synchronization:

[image]

How PC synchronization is seen in the web UI:

[image]

(1) https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Comment: Hi, do you mean the Google Drive desktop client?

Comment: No, I mean the web interface at https://drive.google.com/

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "Computer"? I can't find this in the web interface, can you describe how to set up a file that would appear in this category?

Comment: Added screenshots showing how to configure computer synchronization in Backup & Sync and how it is seen in web UI.

Comment: I see. The [`q` parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms) is limited, some terms do not work for shared drives for instance, I imagine that files in "computers" will also be limited in what `q` can do. Maybe make a feature request in [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I've submitted an issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172775993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is not currently a feature of the Drive API

Here is the current feature request: [issuetracker.google.com/issues/172775993](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172775993),  filed by @josuegomes. Be sure to mark the ☆ to let Google know that you want this feature and to subscribe to future updates regarding it.

There is also another older feature request here: [issuetracker.google.com/issues/70334122](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70334122), in which a user mentions a workaround to list the files inside one of the "Computers" *if you have the name of the computer*. Though it is understood that the issue that @josuegomes wants to solve is *getting* the names of the computers via the API, which is not possible at this time.